# tp-link router does not load

Tags: networking, router

So I've launched my tp-link router (TL-WR741ND) after couple months of disuse and it does not boot properly. Led is stuck on 'settings' icon (cogwheel). Can not access settings page (192.168.0.1) and

```
ping 192.168.0.1
```

shows

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

Tried factory reset (8-10 sec reset button) nothing changes.

Any ideas?
I have Ubuntu. Maybe I can access settings via terminal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried 192.168.1.1 as the IP? I am seeing that as the default IP.

Comment: @MrStatic  I have. same thing

Comment: Have you confirmed that you are trying to connecting to the correct IP address? What about a hard reset?

Comment: Try doing a hard reset using the 30/30/30 rule.